# How to map array [1,2,3] to [1,1,2,2,3,3] in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for the quickest way to map array:

```
[1,2,3]
```

to

```
[1,1,2,2,3,3]
```

I ended up with something like below. But it's not what I need.

```
[1,2,3].map { |n| [n,n] } => [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
```

Comment: There's also `arr.zip(arr).flatten` and `arr.each_with_object([]) { |n,a| a << n << n }`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try `flat_map`

```
arr.flat_map { |n| [n, n] } # => [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Although answer by Bartek is perfectly valid, the more generic way to map an array

```
[a, b, c]
```

to

```
[a, a, ..., a, b, b, ..., b, c, c, ..., c]
#\__________/  \__________/  \__________/
#     n              n             n
```

Would be:

```
MAPPER = ->(arr, n) { arr.flat_map { |e| [e] * n } } 
MAPPER.([1, 2, 3], 2)
#⇒ [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming when the OP asks for quickest, he means in terms of computation. Some benchmarks:

```
require 'fruity'
arr = [1, 2, 3]
MAPPER = ->(ar, n) { ar.flat_map { |e| [e] * n } }
compare do
  barteck_gladys {ar = arr.dup; ar.flat_map{|n| [n,n]} }
  mudasobwa      {ar = arr.dup; MAPPER.(ar, 2)}
end

#Running each test 1024 times. Test will take about 1 second.
#barteck_gladys is faster than mudasobwa by 2x ± 0.1
```

For `arr = (1..100).to_a`:

```
#Running each test 32 times. Test will take about 1 second.
#barteck_gladys is faster than mudasobwa by 2x ± 1.0
```

For `arr = (1...1000).to_a`:

```
#Running each test 4 times. Test will take about 1 second.
#barteck_gladys is faster than mudasobwa by 2x ± 0.1
```

Comment: What if the array was `[3, 2, 1]`.

Comment: @ndn great point, then the result for my solution would be incorrect whereas mudasowba's and bartek's would be correct. Think I'll remove my solution and update the benchmarks with the correct answers only. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

`Array.new(2) { [1,2,3] }.flatten.sort # => [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]`

This approach is flexible, as you can now easily increase the number of occurrences of each integer in the `Array` e.g

`Array.new(3) { [1,2,3] }.flatten.sort # => [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]`